# Flex regular expression String

Tags: regex, string, lex, flex-lexer

I've got a regular expression that matches strings opening with `"` and closing with `"` and can contain `\"`.

The regular expression is this `\"".*[^\\]"\"`.

I don't understand what's the `"` that is followed after `\"` and after the `[^\\]`.

Also this regular expression works when I have a `\n` inside a string but the `.` rule on flex doesn't match a `\n`.

I just tested for example the string `"aaaaa\naaa\naaaa"`.

It matched it with no problem.

I made a regex for flex that matches what I need. It's this one `\"(([^\\\"])|([\\\"]))*\"`. I understand how this works though.

Also I just tested my solutions against an `""` an empty string. It doesn't work. Also the answers from all those that answered have been tested and don't work as well.

Comment: Your new pattern is false for the same reason I explained in my answer (it is unable to match a literal backslash before the closing quote.)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes you are quite right it doesn't work. Although that's no reason to down vote my question as well as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is a little naive and even indeed false. It doesn't handle correctly escaped quotes because it assumes that the closing quote is the first one that is not preceded by a backslash. This is a false assumption.

The closing quote can be preceded by a literal backslash *(a backslash that is escaped with an other backslash, so the second backslash is no longer escaping the quote)*, example: `"abcde\\"` (so the content of this string is `abcde\`)

This is the pattern to deal with all cases:

```
\"[^"\\]*(?s:\\.[^"\\]*)*\"
```

or perhaps *(I don't know exactly where you need to escape literal quotes in a flex pattern)*:

```
\"[^\"\\]*(?s:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"
```

Note that the s modifier allows the dot to match newlines inside the non capturing group.

Comment: Your first regex causes flex an error. Your second regex doesn't match `"aaa\n\"\"\n\\aaa"` or `"aaa\n\"\"\n\\aaa\\"`. The one that I propose matches this `"aaa\n\"\"\n\\aaa"` but not this `"aaa\n\"\"\n\\aaa\\"`. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out everything :P

This `\"".*[^\\]"\"` works because in flex it means: I want to match something that starts with `"` and ends with `"`. Inside these quotes there will be another matching pattern(that's why there are the unexplained `"`, as I was pondering their existence in my question) that can be any set of any characters, but CANNOT end with `\`.

What confused me more was the use of `.`, cause in flex it means that it will match any character except a new line `\n`. So I was mistakenly thinking that it won't match a string such as `"aaa\naaa"`.

But the reality is it will match it, because when flex reads it will read first `\` and then `n`.

The TRUE newline would be, something like this:

`"something
like
this"`

But compilers in -ansi C for example(haven't tested it on other versions other than ansi) do not let you declare a string using in different lines.

I hope my answer is clear enough. Cheers.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it) by clicking on the tick. This remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @BrianTompsett None of the answers are correct.. Neither mine.. If you have one please share it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; however if your answer is not  an answer it should have really been a question edit! The words *"I just figured out everything"* & *"I hope my answer is clear enough"* imply you were happy with it and felt it correct. Yes: I can answer it correctly, now you have clarified.

Comment: @BrianTompsett Thank you, you are right, it should have been an edit. Although at the time I thought I had figured it out. Waiting for your answer :)

Comment: A flex program containing your regular expression does not work (just tested it) - are you wanting one that does work? If you want your expression explained can you edit the Q to include a whole flex program please. I think you are confused by what you have.

Comment: @BrianTompsett I've figured out excactly what my regex does. It doens't solve the problem though. I've explained my regex in full detail in my (false) answer. What I would like is a solution that works. No need for explanations I think. There's a bunch info in all our answers and comments for people to read.

Comment: I have several solutions lined up. Your problem specification is not unambiguous. Do you want something that matches strings over several lines?

Comment: @BrianTompsett No, not several lines, as that's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76253/discussion-between-brian-tompsett-and-konstantinos).

Answer (score -1):

Your pattern does not match "hello" but it matches ""hello"".

if you want to match anything that is in quotes and may contain \" try something like:

```
/(\"[\na-zA-Z\\"]*\")/gs
```

Comment: You are wrong. It matches "hello" fine. I just tested it.

Comment: The thing is though that just by looking at it, I would also say it doesn't match "hello". But IT DOES. And that's why I asked. How is it possible to work?

Comment: I tried it in regex101.com and it did not work.

Comment: Try it using lex please. My question is specific.